# Tables created by sonar in the database

Tags: sonarqube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the sonar database structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193749/what-is-the-sonar-database-structure)

Just want to ask which tables will be created after sonar get connected to the database? And also tables used to store the information like "Lines of code" "Classes" "Comments" etc. Could any one give me some documentation about these? Thanks

Comment: The sonarsource team do not document their database schema. Instead you should use the REST API for reporting http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API#WebServiceAPI-Metrics

Answer (score 3):

If you have a clean database with no tables, then Sonar will create all the required tables the first time you start it.

To know more about the tables, you can have a look at this DDL file that we are using for our tests:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/server/sonar-db-core/src/main/resources/org/sonar/db/version/schema-h2.ddl

The project split, but the 4.5.5 version of the DDL orginally linked in the answer can be found here:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/4.5.5/sonar-core/src/main/resources/org/sonar/core/persistence/schema-h2.ddl

Comment: Hi Fabrice : This Is a very old thread, the link is dead now.. Can you please update the link with the DDL file?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the notification!