# Sonar database structure & sonar api metrics

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have two questions regarding sonar:

1. I have taken a look at the database of sonar. I was wondering where sonar stores the results of each measurement?

   I found only the table `measure_data`, but the field data looks to me like a has value.
   Can anyone tell me where sonar stores the data of all measurements?

   Yes I know, that it is better to use the REST API, and I will do it, but I also want to know, how the database is used by sonar itself.
2. Is there a way by using the API to get a full list of all used metrics?

Comment: Have a look at rule_failures. It contains some data on violations that may be helpful

Comment: thanks, that is a good one.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193749/what-is-the-sonar-database-structure/9202474#9202474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured question number 2 out:

```
List<Metric> smq = sonar.findAll(MetricQuery.all());
    System.out.println(smq);

    for(int i = 0; i< smq.size(); i++){
       System.out.println(smq.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer the first question as Sonar DB is not an API and might change at any point of time.

For your second question: the WS you're looking for is the ["/api/metrics" WS](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743272). For instance, you can see all the metrics that are registered on Nemo - our Sonar live instance, here: http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/metrics

Comment: Thank you, found it already by searching. Are there any Java examples additional to this one: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client or do I have to figure it out myself by reading the java doc and the api documentation?

Comment: You should indeed have a look to the Javadoc to find what you're looking for.